# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 - Pull data from subject of incoming email

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata

I am currently creating a SharePoint site that's primary job (at least initially) is to be an SSRS report suppository.  In order to properly sort and store the reports, I need to somehow send metadata from my SSRS subscription to the SharePoint library where it will reside.  The only way that I have been able to do this is through the subject line of the incoming email from SSRS.  Unfortunately, I've been researching this and there doesn't seem to be a way in SharePoint Foundation 2010 to easily do this.  I've found a third party solution that would do it for me, but my company is not interested in that, and I've found where I can add code to use the SPEmailEventReceiver class :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a880daab-dba4-42fb-8615-7751fcd0b946/insert-incoming-email-subject-to-document-library-field?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

I've tried to use this code, but I don't have Visual Studio installed on the same server as SharePoint, so it isn't letting me.

My question is:  Is there a way to do this in SharePoint through workflows or any basic functionality?  If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how I can send the metadata in a way that it is accessible to me?  Thank you for your help and your patience, as I am very new to SharePoint development.

Answer (score 0):

Incoming email functionality is good way how to get documents automatically into SharePoint. Especially when you have only limited options. But using SPEmailEventReceiver is not necessary. SPEmailEventReceiver is handy when you need completely control "the import" of received email into SharePoint. I suggest you to use standard item event receiver (SPItemEventReceiver) and it's ItemAdded method. This method is executed when item (email and attachments in your case) is added into document library. You can find [here](http://sharepointquester.com/2012/07/24/configuring-incoming-email-on-a-sharepoint-2010-document-library/) how to configure storing emails into document library. The email's file name is the same as the subject of email.